# backward many to many Django query

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class tags(models.Model):
    """ This is the tag model """
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=15)               # Tag name
    tagDescription = models.TextField()                 # Tag Description
    tagSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)          # Extra info can be added to the existing tag using this field
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # Time at which tag is created
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)     # Time at which tag is updated

class stores(models.Model):
    """ This is the store model """
    storeName = models.CharField(max_length=15)                                          # Store Name
    storeDescription = models.TextField()                                                # Store Description
    storeURL = models.URLField()                                                         # Store URL
    storePopularityNumber = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES,default=2)                # Store Popularity Number  
    storeImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")                                   # Store Image 
    storeSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)                                         # This is the text you see in the URL
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                  # Time at which store is created
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                                      # Time at which store is updated
    storeTags = models.ManyToManyField(tags)                                             # All the tags associated with the store
```

I want to find out all the stores related to a particular tag.
`for t in tags.objects.all():
    print  ([str(a.storeName) for a in t.stores_set.all()])`
By using above for loop i am able to get all the tags related to all the stores...But actually  i am using Django rest-frameWork...Now i have a view which uses a serializer to return the names of the stores related to stores...

```
class tagList(generics.ListAPIView,APIView):

    serializer_class = getAllTagsDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        key = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('appKey', None)
        getTagName = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('tagName', None)
        keyData = app.objects.filter(appKey=key).exists()    
        try:
            if keyData == True:

                return tags.objects.filter(tag=getTagName)
            else:
                raise exceptions.PermissionDenied
        except app.DoesNotExist:
            pass

`class getAllStoresDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    storeImage = serializers.Field(source='imageURL')
    storeTags =serializers.Field(source='StoreTags')

    class Meta:
        model = stores
        fields = ('storeName','storeDescription','storeURL',
                    'storePopularityNumber','storeImage','storeTags',
                    'storeSlug','createdAt','updatedAt'
                 )`


class getAllTagsDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tagStores = RelatedField(Many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = tags
        fields = ('tagStores'                   
                    )
```

But this is not working...can anyone help me please ...

Comment: Your model is `stores`, so use `stores_set`. You tried with `store_set` and possibly that's why you got ` 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'store_set' `

Comment: Always name your model classes in the singular and the class names with initial caps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ...

This the class which handles get request...

```
class tagList(generics.ListAPIView,APIView):
    model = tags
    serializer_class = getAllTagsDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        key = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('appKey', None)
        getTagName = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('tagName', None)
        keyData = app.objects.filter(appKey=key).exists()    
        try:
            if keyData == True:
                return tags.objects.filter(tag=getTagName)
            else:
                raise exceptions.PermissionDenied
        except app.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

This Serializer class:

```
class getAllTagsDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tagStores = serializers.Field(source='getAllStoreNames')

    class Meta:
        model = tags
        fields = ('tagStores')
```

And this is my tags model:

```
class tags(models.Model):
    """ This is the tag model """
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=15)               # Tag name
    tagDescription = models.TextField()                 # Tag Description
    tagSlug = models.CharField(max_length=400)          # Extra info can be added to the existing tag using this field
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # Time at which tag is created
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)     # Time at which tag is updated

    def __unicode__(self):
        """Method to display string correctly"""
        return unicode(self.tag)

    def getAllStoreNames(self):

        for t in tags.objects.filter(tag=self.tag):      
            return  ([str(a.storeName) for a in t.stores_set.all()])

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to control display Behavior of the Model name """
        verbose_name_plural = "Tags"
```

Let me explain a bit if any one want to know...
In my class tagList im setting a query set by return `tags.objects.filter(tag=getTagName)` Which will filter out all the names of stores based on the tagName specified ...Then it goes to serializer class where i am setting `tagStores = serializers.Field(source='getAllStoreNames')` Then it reads the fields values and call the `getAllStoreNames` which is inside the tags model which is returning the names of Store related tag... If anyone know much more efficient solution please do share...

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, with your tag:

```
tag.store_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = Tag.objects.get(pk=1)
stores = t.stores_set.all()
```

Comment: related name is to a field, not to a model. It should be `storeTags_set`

Comment: @karthikr No it should be `stores_set`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ and `Article`, `Publication` example. Its `p2.article_set.all()` and not `p2.publication_set.all()`

Comment: would you like to help the OP?